# How to extract a column

Tags: python

```
def hurst(ts):
    """Returns the Hurst Exponent of the time series vector ts"""
```

I read a csv file and parse the columns into parsed:

```
try:
    with open(file) as csvfile:                
        parsed = (
    (row['time'],
    float(row['bid']),
    int(row['bid_depth']),
    int(row['bid_depth_total']),
    float(row['offer']),
    int(row['offer_depth']),
    int(row['offer_depth_total']))    
    for row in reader)
```

I can print this fine:

```
for row in parsed:
    print(row)
```

But how do I pass say the entire column of floats row[bid] to the function hurst?

Comment: Use a different data structure, such as a dict: keys for columns names, values are lists of column values. [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) is the next logical thing to use, really: it can read a CSV file in one go, and produce a column in the next line of code.

Comment: Try ```transpose = zip(*parsed) ; bid = transpose[1]```. Then pass ```bid``` as the argument.

Comment: Thank you both that helped.

Comment: `hurst(x[1] for x in parsed)` but given `parsed` is a generator you can only go through this once so this is equivalent to `hurst(float(row['bid'] for row in reader)`. You need a list or other structure if you want to reuse `parsed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension

```
mylist = [x for x in [r['bid'] for r in parsed]]
```

Now pass `mylist` to your function.

Comment: `parsed` is a generator of tuples, so this wouldn't work. Did you mean `for r in reader`? What is the purpose of the nested list comprehension?